# Using burst_read/write with register model

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I've a register space of 16 registers.
These are accessible through serial bus (single as well as burst).
I've UVM reg model defined for these registers.
However none of the reg model method supports burst transaction on bus.

As a workaround

1. I can declare memory model for same space and whenever I need burst access I use memory model but it seems redundant to declare 2 separate classes for same thing and this approach won't mirror register values correctly.
2. create a function which loops for number of bytes iterations and access registers one by one however this method doesn't create burst transaction on bus.

So I would like to know if there is a way to use burst_read and burst_write methods with register model. It would be nice if burst_read and burst_write support mirroring (current implementation doesn't support this) but if not I can use .predict and .set so its not big concern.

Or can I implement a method for register model easily to support burst operation.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to write to all 16 registers in one burst?

Comment: I mean accessing any number of registers greater than 1 i.e. read/write 2, 5, 8, 16 (any number) of registers in burst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After combining opinions provided by Tudor and links in the discussion, here is what works for adding burst operation to reg model.

This implementation doesn't show all the code but only required part for adding burst operation, I've tested it for write and read operation with serial protocols (SPI / I2C). Register model values are updated correctly as well as RTL registers are updated.

Create a class to hold data and burst length:

```
class burst_class extends uvm_object;
 `uvm_object_utils (....);

  int burst_length;
  byte data [$];

  function new (string name);
    super.new(name);
  endfunction

endclass
```

Inside register sequence (for read don't initialize data)

```
burst_class obj;
obj = new ("burstInfo");

obj.burst_length = 4; // replace with actual length
obj.data.push_back (data1);
obj.data.push_back (data2);
obj.data.push_back (data3);
obj.data.push_back (data4);

start_reg.read (status,...., .extension(obj));
start_reg.write (status, ...., .extension (obj));
```

After successful operation data values should be written or collected in obj object
In adapter class (reg2bus is updated for write and bus2reg is updated for read)
All the information about transaction is available in reg2bus except data in case of read.

adapter class
      uvm_reg_item start_reg;
      int burst_length;
      burst_class adapter_obj;

reg2bus implementation

```
  start_reg = this.get_item;
  adapter_obj = new ("adapter_obj");

  if($cast (adapter_obj, start_reg.extension)) begin
     if (adapter_obj != null) begin
        burst_length     = adapter_obj.burst_length;
     end
     else
        burst_length              = 1; /// so that current implementation of adapter still works
  end
```

Update the size of transaction over here according to burst_length and assign data correctly. 
As for read bus2reg needs to be updated

bus2reg implementation (Already has all control information since reg2bus is always executed before bus2reg, use the values captured in reg2bus)

According to burst_length only assign data to object passed though extension in this case adapter_obj

Comment: I've written a post on the topic of accessing registers in a burst. It covers using the 'extension' argument and another alternative way of doing it. You can find it here: http://blog.verificationgentleman.com/2015/11/accessing-multiple-registers-at-once.html

Comment: How is burst read being handled and multiple read values passed to the caller sequence? Burst read transaction was called correctly, but it only returns one value. It's been a long time since this question was answered, but I thought to give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to help get you started:

http://forums.accellera.org/topic/716-uvm-register-model-burst-access/

The guy mentions using the optional 'extension' argument that read/write take. You could store the length of the burst length inside a container object (think `int` vs. `Integer` in Java) and then pass that as an argument when calling `write()` on the first register.

A rough sketch (not tested):

```
// inside your register sequence
uvm_queue #(int) container = new("container");
container.push_front(4);
start_reg.write(status, data, .extension(container));


// inside your adapter
function uvm_sequence_item reg2bus(const ref uvm_reg_bus_op rw);
  int burst_len = 1;

  uvm_reg_item reg_item = get_item();
  uvm_queue #(int) extension;
  if ($cast(extension, reg_item.extension))
    burst_len = extension.pop_front();

  // do the stuff here based on the burst length
  // ...
endfunction
```

I've used `uvm_queue` because there isn't any trivial container object in UVM.

Comment: Thanks, I'll need to spend some time with it. I'll let you know :)

Comment: I'll write a post about this in my blog when I get a chance (including code), but that's going to take a bit. If you hit any more snags let me know.

Comment: I'm trying to copy-paste exact same code however compilation fails with `pop_front is not class item` Do I need to typedef extension of type queue?

Comment: Like I said, the code is not tested, it was just of the top of my head. What's missing is a cast to uvm_queue #(int). I'll update the answer to include that.

Comment: Ah, I was trying static cast, compilation was going through but was failing in elaboration phase. Thanks :)

Comment: How to pass multiple bytes through uvm_reg_data_t?

Comment: I think I get what you mean, you want to pass in the values to be written to each register. I guess it's not enough to pass just the burst length as the extension; we need an own type that contains the burst length and the data values to be written to each register. I'm having a change of heart and think it may be better to create a subclass of `uvm_reg` that contains `burst_write` and `burst_read` methods, similar to what exists for `uvm_mem`.

Comment: I'm reading http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/uvm/UVM_1.1_Class_Reference_Final_06062011.pdf and it seems uvm_reg_data_t is 64 bits by default and can be changed with define, so I'm gonna try combining bunch of data in single big variable and try using that

Comment: Larger data than 8 bits was not a solution cause while declaring register model size is fixed to 8bit for start_reg (1st address of burst) and anything passed greater than 8 bits is discarded. So I tried implementing burst according to http://forums.accellera.org/topic/584-uvm-regread-and-write-documentation/ However if I use `reg_item.extension.class_field` I get compilation error about `not a class item`

Comment: I got it working with above (comment) method, had to construct an object and typecast extension to that object. I'll clean up code and run it few times, will paste it here by tomorrow.