# Register Abstraction Layer Difference Access Type

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I am writing a set of register models using uvm_reg class. Individual register size is 8-bit. Register block is created to contains those registers:

```
class my_reg_block extends uvm_reg_block;
  my_byte_reg reg_00;
  my_byte_reg reg_01;
  my_byte_reg reg_10;
  my_byte_reg reg_11;
  ...
  // build()
  my_map.add_reg(reg_00, 32'h0000 /*offset*/, ""RW");
  my_map.add_reg(reg_01, 32'h0001 /*offset*/, ""RW");
  my_map.add_reg(reg_10, 32'h0002 /*offset*/, ""RW");
  my_map.add_reg(reg_11, 32'h0003 /*offset*/, ""RW");
  ...
```

I have a register adapter that will translate read/write into bus transaction.
So, I am able to do this inside my sequence:

```
reg_00.write(status, 'hff, .parent(this));
```

The bus transaction will do write to that specific register: `reg_00`.

My problem is that the bus has `byte_enable` that allow it to write accross 4 register in double-word access. Using the existing register model above, is it possible to write/read in 4 register at the same time? Or do I need to create another set of registers (with 32-bit size)?
It would be something like this pseudo-code:

```
{reg_11,reg_10,reg_01,reg_00}.write(status, 'hffffffff, .parent(this));
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Seems you are looking for burst transfer. May be [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143815/using-burst-read-write-with-register-model) can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try passing additional information like byte_enable to the adapter using the extension argument in the write function. Then the adapter can decide accordingly if this is a legal double word transaction  and assign the bus transaction fields accordingly. see partial example below

```
virtual function uvm_sequence_item reg2bus(const ref uvm_reg_bus_op rw);
bus_trans            trans;
uvm_reg_item            item;
regtrans_params         params;


item                    = get_item();
trans                   = bus_trans::type_id::create("trans");

if(item.extension == null) 
  `uvm_fatal("", "item.extension==null !!")
if(!$cast(params, item.extension))
  `uvm_fatal("", "FAILED $cast(params, item.extension) !!")

trans.dst_chip_addr              = params.chip_addr;
```

in the sequence:

```
block.reg_00.write(status, 32'hfffffffff .extension(params));
```